# Orientation Change Default Time Delay...?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I am wondering to know that what time a device approximately takes to change the orientation, when we rotate it. In my app when i rotate my phone device, it approximately takes 1 to 2 sec's to rotate the screen. Now my question is, Is it a normal span or it's a delayed span. So that i can work on it accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when orientation changes Your current Activity is destroyed and reloaded.So you can think it takes time from what it takes starting from onCreate Method

Comment: @Rasel...Absolutely this is what i am thinking, but somebody told me your orientation change is slow, that's why i thought, i better consult it with people on Stackoverflow. Can we rotate app without destroying activity..?????

Comment: Yes you can. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html Oh. And you will also have to read about onConfigurationChanged http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

From a little code research, it looks like it takes at least 200ms before rotating the view. This delay is to make sure the change in device orientation is intentional.

Code snippet from [WindowOrientationListener.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.0.4_r1/core/java/android/view/WindowOrientationListener.java) for reference:

```
// The number of milliseconds for which the device posture must be stable
// before we perform an orientation change.  If the device appears to be rotating
// (being picked up, put down) then we keep waiting until it settles.
private static final int SETTLE_TIME_MIN_MS = 200;
```

Comment: "This delay is to make sure the change in orientation is intentional." This doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @Biu, in cases where user puts the device on the table or picks it up or such, the device orientation may be changed briefly, however, the user might not really intend to change the orientation of the view. To prevent orienting the view in such cases, which are quite common, the code makes sure that the new/changed orientation of the device is stable for certain duration (`SETTLE_TIME_MIN_MS`) before it rotates the view to compensate the new orientation of the device. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Biu, for code level understanding of this logic, please refer to `onSensorChanged()` method of WindowOrientationListener.java  (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.0.4_r1/core/java/android/view/WindowOrientationListener.java)

Answer (score -2):

add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` inside the Manifest file. For example

```
<activity
            android:name="example.pangasinantranslator.MainActivity"            
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```